# Changing HTML5 element to military time in Webform

Tags: 8, webforms

Would anyone be able to suggest a way that I can change the current AM/PM default 12-hour HTML5 time into 24-hour military time when using the Date/time element in Webform?

When I change it to 'Time picker input,' it does give me the 24-hour time as an output, but it's not the format I want. I like the 'HTML Time input' format and would just like to keep that but take away the AM/PM and make it 24 hrs instead of 12.

Comment: Can't these have a Date Format set from the list of date formats in Drupal? If so, you can create a new one to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately the only time formats that are offered in Webform are in the text format... Was wondering if there was any way (maybe in YAML?) to make it show up in HTML5 format.